# Finding a specfic int in a List

Tags: c#, list, class, int, indexof

I have a list which is created from a Class:

```
class Vara
{
    public int streckKod { get; set; }
    public string artNamn { get; set; }
}
```

And the list looks like this:

```
List<Vara> minaVaror = new List<Vara>();
```

And I add to the list with this line:

```
minaVaror.Add(new Vara() {streckKod = inputBox1, artNamn = textBox2.Text });
```

But what I'm stuck at is how I can find a specific int within the list. Let's say I'm searching for the item in my list holding the number 293 in the variable streckKod.

I've tried using .IndexOf function but I haven't gotten it to work properly.

Also would it be possible to get the item number that the specific number is located in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to find all items whose `streckKod` value is 293 use `Where`

```
var items = minaVaror.Where(i => i.streckKod == 293);
```

If interested in only first item use `FirstOrDefault` -

```
var item = minaVaror.FirstOrDefault(i => i.streckKod == 293);
```

`FirstOrDefault` will `return null in case no item exist in collection` with value 293.

**Make sure you add namespace `System.Linq` in your class to use these `LINQ extension methods`.**

Comment: And if you don't want to use Linq, you would have to iterate the list with either for (int i = 0; i < minaVaror.Count; i++) and match 'streckKod' here. Or use foreach (Vara item in minaVaror) and match 'streckKod' here. .IndexOf() gives you the position of a specific Vara in the list minaVaror. So when you have found the exact Vara item you need the index of, you can call minaVaror.IndexOf(item)

Comment: Just one more question, would it now be possible to convert this position from var item to an int? :)

Comment: Yeah use - `int index = (item == null)? -1 : minaVaror.IndexOf(item)`.

Comment: If item is null, it should be -1 that means it doesn't exist in the list. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use Linq

```
minaVarror.Find(item=>item.strekKod == 293);
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Rohit Vats answer...

When you have found your item, with either `Where` or `FirstOrDefault` you can get the index by doing:

```
var item = minaVaror.FirstOrDefault(i => i.streckKod == 293);

// Get index of Vara (item) with streckKod = 293
int index = minaVaror.IndexOf(item);
```

As `IndexOf` returns the position of an exact item (Vara) within the list `minaVaror`